# Acessar array multidimensional AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Basicamente tenho que pegar as informações no banco e jogar na tela, então quis fazer uma tela só com as de "Avaliações" e que, ao clicar em algum botão, me mostrará os treinos.

Porem estou com duvida de como acessar o array "Treinos" (Segue um print_r do meu array data)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [AvaliacaoId] => 1
            [AvaliacaoNome] => a
            [AvaliacaoDescricao] => 
            [AvaliacaoTreino] => 1
            [AvaliacaoTimeId] => 1
            [AvaliacaoCategoriaId] => 1
            [Treinos] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [TreinoId] => 1
                            [TreinoNome] => Fisico
                            [TreinoData] => 2015-10-09
                            [TreinoHorario] => 14:00:00
                            [TreinoTipo] => 1
                            [TreinoCategoria] => 1
                            [TreinoTimeId] => 1
                            [TreinoFinalizado] => 1
                            [TreinoTurno] => 1
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Na minha view estou com um AJAX que usa o  `response.content` para pegar os dados. Na parte de avaliação ficaria  `response.content[i].AvaliacaoNome`, agora no de Treinos eu não sei.
Alguma ideia?

Comment: Sugiro a leitura do guia [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Edite sua pergunta e adicione a resposta JSON e os métodos JS utilizados na recuperação e tratamento do retorno.

Comment: Isso ai é um json? ou  vc recebe como texto puro?

Comment: `response.content[i].Treinos[j].TreinoId` ?

Comment: @rray Na verdade eu fiz apenas um print_r do array que estou codificando em JSON, no meu PHP. Só pra terem uma ideia certinho, vou atualizar com o JSON ali.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert tentei isso, porem não consigo. Parece ser erro de sincronização do AJAX. Vou até criar outra pergunta pra tratar isso haha

Comment: Essa estrutura é um array em PHP: `$saida = $seuarray[0]['Treinos'][0];` no javascript, seria assim: `var saida = collection[0].Treinos[0]`, onde a variável saída representa o array de treinos. Você pode arrancar esses índices "0", pois pelo que parece você não está usando, dá pra fazer isso com o `array_values()`.

Comment: Aqui tem o exemplo: http://www.viper-7.com/UXkJvW

Comment: Aqui com os dois exemplos: http://www.viper-7.com/ZivcDS